# Terraform Remote State using incorrect file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt

We are using Terraform with an S3 backend via Terragrunt. Recently, someone tried to use a Terraform workspace, and subsequently deleted the workspace, not our remote state cannot find any of the outputs which are in the correct state file.

Upon looking at the debug log, I can see it looks to be pointing to the right file, but it is not picking up any of the already deployed infrastructure or outputs

Comment: You don't have versioning enabled on the S3 bucket so that you can get your state back to what it was?

Comment: Also, make sure you backup and delete all terraform files locally, so that the new, downloaded state is the one that is picked up.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform workspace and terragrunt using different backend key path. And if you run with `terragrunt`, the s3 bucket has version control enabled as default.

For example, using `terraform workspace`, the real `*.tfstate` file will be created to

```
s3://<nominated_backend_bucket>/env:/<workspace_name>/<tfstate_path>
```

But terragrunt will create the tfstate path as

```
s3://<nominated_backup_bucket>/<source_code_directory>/<tfstate_path>
```

So in most cases, they will have no chance to conflict each other.

I recommend to clean your environment and run `terragrunt plan/apply` again. There are some other problems more than you described in your original question and you need find out by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestions